# For a binary search where the element isn't found, how to return the index it should be inserted into

Tags: java, algorithm

I'd like to use a binary search to find the array index that an element should be placed at. This for the purposes of inserting the element into the array while moving down larger elements. How could this binary search be modified to specify the location that non-found elements should be placed at?

```
    int binarySearch(int arr[], int x) {

        int low = 0;
        int mid = 0;
        int high = arr.length - 1;
        while (low <= high) {
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if (x < arr[mid]) {
                high = mid - 1;
            } else if (x > arr[mid]) {
                low = mid + 1;
            } else {
                return mid;
            }
        }
        //This is what im trying to get to work
        if (x < arr[mid]) {
            return high;
        } else {
            return low;
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays.binarySearch() returns `-(insertion_point + 1)`. That way, return values ≥ 0 are hits and return values < 0 are misses, with `insertion_point = -return_value - 1`.

Comment: And `-(x + 1) = ~x = -x -1`, just FYI :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at how java.util.Arrays.binarySearch() does it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [lower_bound](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/lower_bound.html) and [upper_bound](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/upper_bound.html) in the C++ Standard Template Library. Those links are to the specifications; the implementations are in the file stl_algo.h in the implementation section of the same web site but I'm a new user and thus not allowed to post more than two URLs at a time.